# Setting up Javafx with Maven IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Hi I followed this tutorial step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ri6No63fl-A&t=285s

Which is basically the tutorial on 
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

but for some reason when I run the jfx it gives me this error. I don't know why.

```
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: [What is a null pointer exception and how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Please check your `Workbench.builder()`

Comment: The javafx-maven-plugin is at version 0.0.4 now. Your tutorial must be very old or you just made a mistake here.